# Spring Validation adds suffix to my message code

Tags: java, spring, forms, validation

I'm trying to implement form validation with Spring Validator, following these tutorials from [dzone](https://dzone.com/tutorials/java/spring/spring-form-validation-1.html) and [mkyong](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-form-handling-example).
It seems the **Validator** method **validate** is called upon form submission, errors are thrown, but the message codes aren't the same that I specified.
I have a bean named **Song** with an attribute name **title**
In my Validator, I have 
    `ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "title", "title.required");`

yet, I got this error message
`org.springframework.context.NoSuchMessageException: No message found under code 'title.required.song.title' for locale 'en_US'.`

it searches the message under **title.required.song.title** instead of **title.required**, and I guess under a file name messages_en_US.properties

How can I change this behaviour?

My **messages.properties** placed under `/src/` folder has
`title.required=Ce champ est obligatoire`

```
@Entity
public class Song {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;

private String title;
//and other stuff
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this to your configuration xml :

```
<bean id="messageSource"
     class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource"
     p:basename="classpath:messages" />
```

or using config java add this line

```
 @Bean(name = "messageSource")
    public ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource reloadableResourceBundleMessageSource() {
        ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasenames("classpath:messages");
        messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        return messageSource;
    }
```

best regards

Comment: Actually, in my configuration xml, I had **ResourceBundleMessageSource** as in the tutorials instead of **ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource**. the class change solved the issue. thanks (by the way, I still struggle to understand the difference in practice)

Comment: check this url  explain what is the difference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39685399/reloadableresourcebundlemessagesource-vs-resourcebundlemessagesource-cache-con